# How to debug nuget package in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget, nuget-package

I work on my own xamarin nuget package and I would like to know how to debug it in sample or any other project. Right know I have to create nuget package with symbols and then update the package in sample project. In process of developing nuget package this is really time consuming. Do you know any better way how to save some time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Right know I have to create nuget package with symbols and then update the package in sample project. In process of developing nuget package this is really time consuming.

Using [dotpeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html) you can debug any package there is even if it does not contain debug symbols. Personally i would set up a local nuget repository and deploy to that if you're in a testing/debugging stage.

If you're "publishing" to a local nuget and set up a reference in your testing project to that local nuget the time should be pretty minimal.